# How to know in dialog that another dialog is closed using this dialog inside java class in android?

Tags: java, android

I have dialog class, in that class I have one method that opens a dialog.

```
 providerDialog.showProvidersDialog(customCategory.getCustCategoryId());
```

In that method I open another dialog (that is written in another class) to fill some information. Now dialog open and user filled details and I dismissed dialog from that method. Now I want to know in this current dialog class that another last opened dialog is closed so that I can get that details which I share using singleton and want to show in this class.
**Current class method:**

```
 private void showCategoryInformationDialog() {
        LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        informationPromptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.row_category_information_layout, null);

        android.app.AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(context, R.style.dialogBoxStyle);
        // alertDialogBuilder.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
        alertDialogBuilder.setView(informationPromptsView);
        inputBillProvider = informationPromptsView.findViewById(R.id.inputBillProvider);
        inputConsumerNumber = informationPromptsView.findViewById(R.id.inputConsumerNumber);
        name = informationPromptsView.findViewById(R.id.name);

        inputBillProvider.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });

        alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton(context.getString(R.string.add), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton(context.getString(R.string.cancel), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });


        alertDialogBuilder.show();
    }
```

//I want to know that this below dialog is closed                  `providerDialog.showProvidersDialog(customCategory.getCustCategoryId());`

**Another last opened dialog code:**

Link: [Cancel/dismiss alertdialog builder from any other method in same class in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56816466/cancel-dismiss-alertdialog-builder-from-any-other-method-in-same-class-in-androi/)

Comment: can you post the code part which shows `providerDialog.showProvidersDialog(customCategory.getCustCategoryId());`?

Comment: @AMALKG Please check updated question

Comment: where have you called `showProvidersDialog`?

Comment: @AnishaSingh let me know do you want to close first dialog from second one?

Comment: @SanjayBhalani Nope, that's not my requirement. In another dialog, I inflaate data, and in that row when user click in any of item, then only I'm dismissing dialog anf that time I should get acknowledge, that another dialog is closed in my current class.